# Erro ao carregar JSON

Tags: json, android-studio

No link abaixo, tenho um retorno de `JSON`:

http://localhost/hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/produtos.php

está entregando o seguinte retorno:

```
[{"ProdutosidProduto":"1","Produtostipo":"mp","Produtosmodelo":"F540 2 BAN.PNEU. 100 X 60","Produtosbandejas":"2","Produtospeso":"0","Produtosprensagem":"0","ProdutosprecoUnitario":"6500","Produtoscomprimento":"100","Produtoslargura":"60","Produtoscabo":"0","Produtosligacao":"n","Produtospotencia":"0","Produtosconsumo":"0","Produtoscorrente":"0","Produtosdisjuntor":"0","Produtosdescricao":"
Bom Produto","Produtosestoque":"7","ProdutosfreteGratis":"s","Produtosbloqueado":"n"},
```

Sim, tem mais retorno. Porém, coloquei apenas esse para não ficar mais extensa do que está esta pergunta.

E no meu `app`, tenho o seguinte `código`:

```
package com.example.carlos.radiosingular;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.carlos.radiosingular.classes.Produtos;

public class form extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form);
        List<Produtos> produtos = jSon("http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/produtos.php");

        for (Produtos p : produtos) {
            System.out.println(p.getModelo());
        }
    }

    private List<Produtos> jSon(String jsonString) {

        List<Produtos> produtos = new ArrayList<Produtos>();

        try {
            JSONArray produtosLists = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            System.out.println(produtosLists);
            JSONObject produtosList = produtosLists.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray produtosArray = produtosList.getJSONArray("produtos");

            JSONObject produto;

            for (int i = 0; i < produtosArray.length(); i++) {
                produto = new JSONObject(produtosArray.getString(i));
                Produtos produtoCada = new Produtos(

                        produto.getInt("ProdutosidProduto"),
                        produto.getString("Produtostipo"),
                        produto.getString("Produtosmodelo"),
                        produto.getInt("Produtosbandejas"),
                        produto.getInt("Produtospeso"),
                        produto.getInt("Produtosprensagem"),
                        produto.getInt("ProdutosprecoUnitario"),
                        produto.getInt("Produtoscomprimento"),
                        produto.getInt("Produtoslargura"),
                        produto.getString("Produtoscabo"),
                        produto.getString("Produtosligacao"),
                        produto.getInt("Produtospotencia"),
                        produto.getInt("Produtosconsumo"),
                        produto.getInt("Produtoscorrente"),
                        produto.getInt("Produtosdisjuntor"),
                        produto.getString("Produtosdescricao"),
                        produto.getInt("Produtosestoque"),
                        produto.getString("ProdutosfreteGratis"),
                        produto.getString("Produtosbloqueado")
                );
                produtos.add(produtoCada);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("HOT PLATE PRENSAS", "Erro no parsing do JSON", e);
        }

        return produtos;
    }

}
```

O objetivo é, à principio, imprimir um objeto.

Mas, no **console** ***RUN*** sai o seguinte erro:

```
E/HOT PLATE PRENSAS: Erro no parsing do JSON
    org.json.JSONException: Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
        at com.example.carlos.radiosingular.form.jSon(form.java:43)
        at com.example.carlos.radiosingular.form.onCreate(form.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on ViewConfiguration
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x8e5d8c00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x8e5d5ea0
```

Eis a classe `Produtos`:

```
package com.example.carlos.radiosingular.classes;

public class Produtos {

private int idProduto;
private String tipo;
private String modelo;
private int bandejas;
private int peso;
private int prensagem;
private int precoUnitario;
private int comprimento;
private int largura;
private String cabo;
private String ligacao;
private int potencia;
private int consumo;
private int corrente;
private int disjuntor;
private String descricao;
private int estoque;
private String freteGratis;
private String bloqueado;

    public Produtos(
            int idProduto,
            String tipo,
            String modelo,
            int bandejas,
            int peso,
            int prensagem,
            int precoUnitario,
            int comprimento,
            int largura,
            String cabo,
            String ligacao,
            int potencia,
            int consumo,
            int corrente,
            int disjuntor,
            String descricao,
            int estoque,
            String freteGratis,
            String bloqueado) {
        this.idProduto = idProduto;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.bandejas = bandejas;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.prensagem = prensagem;
        this.precoUnitario = precoUnitario;
        this.comprimento = comprimento;
        this.largura = largura;
        this.cabo = cabo;
        this.ligacao = ligacao;
        this.potencia = potencia;
        this.consumo = consumo;
        this.corrente = corrente;
        this.disjuntor = disjuntor;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.estoque = estoque;
        this.freteGratis = freteGratis;
        this.bloqueado = bloqueado;
    }

    public int getIdProduto() {
        return idProduto;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public int getBandejas() {
        return bandejas;
    }

    public int getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public int getPrensagem() {
        return prensagem;
    }

    public int getPrecoUnitario() {
        return precoUnitario;
    }

    public int getComprimento() {
        return comprimento;
    }

    public int getLargura() {
        return largura;
    }

    public String getCabo() {
        return cabo;
    }

    public String getLigacao() {
        return ligacao;
    }

    public int getPotencia() {
        return potencia;
    }

    public int getConsumo() {
        return consumo;
    }

    public int getCorrente() {
        return corrente;
    }

    public int getDisjuntor() {
        return disjuntor;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public int getEstoque() {
        return estoque;
    }

    public String getFreteGratis() {
        return freteGratis;
    }

    public String getBloqueado() {
        return bloqueado;
    }

}
```

Não *printa* nada na tela.

Onde estou errando que está caindo em

```
Log.e("HOT PLATE PRENSAS", "Erro no parsing do JSON", e);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

o que tu tem ali é um json dentro de um json. Terás de fazer algo semelhante com isso:

```
JSONObject cli = new JSONObject();
cli = (JSONObject) clientes.get(0);
JSONArray client = cli.getJSONArray("NomeCliente");
JSONArray cCpf = cli.getJSONArray("CPFCliente");
SONArray cId = cli.getJSONArray("IdCliente");
```

Onde o clientes é a variável que está armazenando o retorno do php

Comment: cli é um array de JSON

Comment: descobri dessa forma         produtos.forEach(produto -> System.out.println(produto.getModelo()));
, mas dá erro de que LAMBDA não é suportsdo na versão 7

Comment: "cli é um array de JSON" é isso. Tu recebe um objeto json que dentro tem um array json. Fazendo assim como te mandei da certo.

Comment: é o contrario então? A string inteira é um objeto e cada nó dese objeto é um array? [{"ProdutosidProduto":"1","......... isto tudo é um só objeto?

Comment: Eu tenho um array de objetos

Comment: Meio que isso, meio complicado de entender.

Comment: estou quase lá: veja essa dúvida, no final dela eu implemento do jeito que está me ensinando: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349577/percorrer-um-array-de-objetos-json-no-android-studio