# Percorrer um array de objetos JSON no Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, json, jsonarray

Recebo por um link o seguinte JSON

```
[{"ProdutosidProduto":"1","Produtostipo":"mp","Produtosmodelo":"F540 2 BAN.PNEU. 100 X 60","Produtosbandejas":"2","Produtospeso":"0","Produtosprensagem":"0","ProdutosprecoUnitario":"6500","Produtoscomprimento":"100","Produtoslargura":"60","Produtoscabo":"0","Produtosligacao":"n","Produtospotencia":"0","Produtosconsumo":"0","Produtoscorrente":"0","Produtosdisjuntor":"0","Produtosdescricao":"
Bom Produto","Produtosestoque":"7","ProdutosfreteGratis":"s","Produtosbloqueado":"n"},
```

Um array de objetos vindos de um arquivo *php*.

Estou tentando recuperar o modelo de cada objeto no objeto de dento do `Android Studio` mas estou em um dilema:

Se eu faço:

```
JSONArray arrayJS
```

Recebo

`Objeto` esperado mas `array` encontrado.

Não sei mais o que fazer.

```
    try {
        JSONArray arrayJS = new JSONArray("http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/produtos.php");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayJS.length(); i++) {
            String modelo =  arrayJS[i]->Produtosmodelo];
            Log.v("Modelo", modelo);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

***EDIT:***
Testando mais um pouco cheguei em:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form);
        try {
            JSONArray arrayJS = new JSONArray("http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/produtos.php");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayJS.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject prod = new JSONObject();
                prod = (JSONObject) arrayJS.get(i);
                String modelo =  prod.Produtosmodelo;
                Log.v("Modelo", modelo);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Mas não consigo receber

```
String modelo =  prod.Produtosmodelo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é porque você busca um Json de array com várias array dentro?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayJS.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray prod = json.getJSONArray(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < prod.length(); ++j) {
                JSONObject produto = prod.getJSONObject(j);
                String modelo =  produto.Produtosmodelo;
                Log.v("Modelo", modelo);
            }
        }
```

Comment: não pode resolver .Produtosmodelo